# Python: cmath returns wrong value for e^(i*pi)

Tags: python, python-3.9, cmath

I was playing around with complex numbers and `cmath` on `Python 3.9` when I tried printing the value for `e^(i*pi)`. Here is my code for it:-

```
import cmath

print(cmath.exp(1.0j * cmath.pi))
print(cmath.cos(cmath.pi) +  (1.0j)*cmath.sin(cmath.pi))
```

Both of these returned `(-1+1.2246467991473532e-16j)` but the imaginary part should not be there (though it is really small in magnitude).

Is there something I am missing in my code? Or is it something to do with `cmath`?

Comment: This has everything to do with how computers work: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems

Comment: Both `e` and `pi` are approximations and the operation raising one to the power of another introduces further inaccuracies, as your computer doesn't deal with real values, but instead with floating point representations of these numbers of limited precision.

Comment: So is there a way to get rid of these inaccuracies? Something like using rounding off functions if they are smaller or larger than a particular value. Would that work?

Comment: @TheRoboticM Since `e` and `pi` are transcendental numbers, any finite-precision computation and representation is going to involve such errors. The best course of action is to become acquainted with the sub-field of mathematics called [numerical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis).

Comment: Ah okay I'll check that out @njuffa. Thanks!